# I'm trying to install this component npm install ngx-treeview --save, but I'm not getting

Tags: angular, npm

I'm trying to install this component: `npm install ngx-treeview --save`, and I'm having this error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: angular-ngx-treeview-app@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@15.2.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"15.2.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^10.0.0" from ngx-treeview@10.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/ngx-treeview
npm ERR!   ngx-treeview@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Jeferson\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-03T14_36_52_656Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Jeferson\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-03T14_36_52_656Z-debug-0.log

npm i @angular/common
```

Comment: Do you have the dependencies installed as described in [https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-treeview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-treeview)?

Answer (score 0):

Use --legacy-peer-deps in the end like  npm install ngx-treeview --legacy-peer-deps
It will work.